# how to use img-thumbnail with Wordpress thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can i add to wordpress thumbnail, class with img-thumbnail
I made like this, but it's not working..

```
<div class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" id="thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [reading the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail). `the_post_thumbnail()` takes two parameters: `$size` and `$attr`. You can specify an image class in the `$attr`:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 
    'post-thumbnail', 
    array( 'class' => 'img-thumbnail img-responsive' )
);
```